# NLTK POS tagset help not working

Tags: nltk, pos-tagger

I downloaded nltk tagset help is not working.

Whenever I try to access tagset meanings by:-

```
nltk.help.upenn_tagset('NN')
```

I get result as :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
nltk.help.upenn_tagset('NN')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\help.py", line 25, in upenn_tagset
_format_tagset("upenn_tagset", tagpattern)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\help.py", line 39, in _format_tagset
tagdict = load("help/tagsets/" + tagset + ".pickle")
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 774, in load
opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 888, in _open
return find(path_, path + ['']).open()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 618, in find
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
Resource 'help/tagsets/upenn_tagset.pickle' not found.  Please
use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
nltk.download()
Searched in:
- 'C:\\Users\\aarushi/nltk_data'
- 'C:\\nltk_data'
- 'D:\\nltk_data'
- 'E:\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Python34\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\aarushi\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

But I already downloaded tagset from models tab by nltk.download()

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `nltk` is telling you, it searched for the file `help/tagsets/upenn_tagset.pickle` in the directories:

```
- 'C:\\Users\\aarushi/nltk_data'
- 'C:\\nltk_data'
- 'D:\\nltk_data'
- 'E:\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Python34\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\aarushi\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

And could not find it.

**Is it there?**

If not, use `nltk.download()` to get it, and make sure it's in one of these directories.

Comment: On searching the directory I found that there's a zip file of tagsets in
C:\Users\aarushi\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\help. So after extracting the upenn_tagset.pickle nltk is able to find it. Thanks.

Comment: The obvious followup would be to unzip it, I suppose. After unzipping it make sure the mentioned file exists and try and run the program again.

Comment: Yes ran the program again after unzipping and command is now working.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri7E2.png "Reference"

Hi ,

Check for above tagged image to summarize what exactly needs to be  downloaded.

One of the fastest and easiest way to resolve this issue by downloading the *help_tagsets* from nltk.download() .

### One can follow below steps:-

> open your jupyter notebook or python shell in your OS(thru terminal).
>
> > ask for nltk.download() - (shell/jupyter) - it will open the GUI.
> >
> > > search the help_datasets in ALL PACKAGES column.

### Just download it :-) Here you go .